# How to load a java script function when the webpage completely gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a web page that contains google charts(representing some data). When ever my web page loads the charts are loaded exactly after the web page is loaded. I am using "select2" to prettify my select boxes. This is my code:

```
$(document).load(function() { $("select").select2(); });
```

but when the page loads nothing happens! but when I use:

```
$(document).change(function() { $("select").select2(); });
```

and then make any change in any of the web page elements, the select boxes are then transformed in the "select2" format. Please help me what can I try? is there any issue of loading the charts after the page load? If yes then why it is not considered as a change in web page?

Comment: Show how you are including the Google charts.

Comment: Please show us how you load your scripts

Comment: I provide JSON formatted data to populate data and then call this 
`google.setOnLoadCallback("Here all my google charts functions")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very important what your requirement is here.

Is it early enough for you to do something when the *DOM* is "*ready*" (which pretty much means, accessible via ECMAscript) or do you need to wait for all kind of resources to be completely and entirely loaded ?

If it is the former, the `DOMContentLoaded` event is your choice. For the latter case, the `window load` event will make you happy.

Using jQuery, this is either

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // do stuff when the DOM is ready
});
```

or

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    // do stuff when all resources (images, iframes, ...) were loaded
});
```

---

If there are any asyncronous processes involved by any 3rd party script-loader, you have no choice but to get into any kind of *callback mechanism*, which should be provided by those scripts.

Comment: @MHS I just updated the answer at the end. It sounds like there is any magic going on which transfers/loads stuff on your site. If thats the case, you need to execute your code at any timer *after* that, which typically is done via *callback functions*

Comment: Just added my function in `google.setOnLoadCallback()` and it worked :)